# Facing Error Window Is Not Defined [ Colsed ]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

See the following code

```
render() {

    const post = this.props.post;

    let postClass = "posts-item";
    if (post.sticky) postClass += " posts-sticky";

    // ⭐ custom code starts here ⭐
    if (post.color) {
      postClass += " post-"+post.color;
    }
    // ⭐ custom code ends here ⭐
    const currentUrl = window ? window.location.href : undefined;
    .......
    ........
}
```

In this code the line `const currentUrl = window ? window.location.href : undefined;` is generating the follwoing error

```
url:  /
{ [ReferenceError: window is not defined] queryErrors: [ [Circular] ] }
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error. Could you log window and see what it prints in your render method?

Comment: console.log(window) is giving window object

Comment: Then why is it giving error of window is not defined. Could you post your project somewhere for debugging?Like github or jsfiddle

Comment: Is this error thrown in the browser or in the server console?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by following code

```
let currentUrl;
    if(Meteor.isClient)
     currentUrl = window ? window.location.href : undefined;
```